# What are "standart names" for denormalisation patterns?

Tags: database-design, denormalization

I'm interested in to know standard names of two database design patterns, or may be "problems" if you are purists:

How you would call those situations/denormalisations? 
I'm using "mirrored attributes" and "flicked foreign key" for myself  but I'm sure nobody will understand me :) . Anyway situations are simple:

1) we have two entities in "parent child" relationship and in the child entity there are not only foreign key attribute but also some other "backuped" attributes of parent entity's. It could be the situation where you have not only streetId in the address entity but also streetName to support the case where the street is absent in your streets list (or what is more often for legacy data).

2) child entity contains "foreign key" that consists from two fields : one identify "parent table", other is "key value in parent table". That means intepreting first, filtering on it, we know which table should join. Of course consistency of this relationship is not maintained on dbms level, but this is still kind of "parent child relationship" that I sometimes see in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In a normalized database, the columns should be dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.  (So help me Codd.)  You can certainly denormalize certain columns for efficiency, but then you have duplicated data in your database.  This duplicated data can get out of sync.

2) If I understand what you're saying correctly, the first column of your "foreign key" identifies which table, while the second column is the actual key that defines the row in that table.  I've also seen this.  It's probably ok for domain type tables (insurance group rates 1, insurance group rates 2, etc.), but indicates a sort of multiple inheritance when used with data tables.  Without seeing the specific instance, I'd say in general that the multiple inheritance could be redefined with a base table and one or more additional tables that extend the base table.

Comment: So do common "names" exist for such type of design decisions?

Comment: First can be named "duplicated data", but this "name" doesn't show "reasons behind" (provide 'ad hoc' attributes  that can't be provided using parent table's entity attributes, since this entity is not find). BUT second: "multiple inheritance FK" worked perfectly in the google :) Respect and thank you.